# How to query which hash I have checked out in a local git repository?

Tags: git, hash

I'm looking for a simple method to query which hash is checked out in my local git repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git rev-list --max-count=1 HEAD
git show --pretty="%H"
git show --pretty="%h"
```

Probably there are others

Comment: Can the result of these be stored in a Windows Batch variable?

Comment: If you are using bash, you can do something like: ```revision=$( git rev-list --max-count=1 HEAD ); echo $revision```. If you are using a windows interpreter (cmd or powershell or whatever), IHNC

Comment: `git rev-parse HEAD` is the simplest, and the one most programs should use.